# Sort array by alphabetical letter

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
$words = array(
    array('Agreement range','Accord'),
    array('Reception','Accueil')
);
```

What I want to do is to sort this array by alphabeltical letter taking into account the first item (Agreement range, reception in that case)

Like this :

```
[A] =>
array('Agreement range','Accord')
[R] =>
array('Reception','Accueil')
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get some pointers on what is expected of you when you ask here. Please don't just post your requirements, you need to show your effort to solve your problem, with an explanation of where and how it failed to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to loop through the *$words* array, and for each element create in a new array (I called *sorted*) en element with the content of the current *words* element, and as key the first letter of the first word of the element.

```
<?php
  $words = array(
      array('Agreement range','Accord'),
      array('Reception','Accueil')
  );

  $sorted = array();

  foreach($words AS $element){
    $sorted[$element[0][0]] = $element;
  }

  print_r($sorted);
?>
```

Here is the output you get:

```
Array ( [A] => Array ( [0] => Agreement range [1] => Accord ) [R] => Array ( [0] => Reception [1] => Accueil ) )
```

Please note that if you have more elements with same first letter of the first word, you will overwrite the existing element with that key in the *sorted* array. To solve this, in case that situation can happen, you can change the loop as follows:

```
foreach($words AS $element){
    if(!isset($sorted[$element[0][0]]))
      $sorted[$element[0][0]] = $element;
    else
      $sorted[$element[0][0]] = array_merge($sorted[$element[0][0]],$element);
  }
```

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that are mere requirement dumps and show no effort on OP's part. By doing the entire work for them, we encourage users to keep posting low quality questions that don't follow the site's guidelines.